# Is there a way remove warning from qml if image source is not available?

Tags: qt, qml

In my QML application I have created a custom delegate component which shows an image. The source is available from C++, but in some cases source is not available for some indexs. then I get error as "Unable to assign [undefined] to QString". How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662715/qml-check-if-file-image-exists-before-getting-the-error. Seems relevant for your task

Comment: I saw that , but with that approach also I will get this warning.
Is it ok to consider that warning as "don't care" ? & do nothing to fix that?

Comment: Please pay your attention to Mitch's answer for post too. As i can see - he creates something like qml flag isFileValid. So, you can give empty string, as Image source when source isn't ok. source: validator.fileValid ? source1 : ""; Or use default stub image, like Mitch. Default image seems more pretty because you will not get invisible element.

Comment: @AnupamSrivastava use `source: url_object ? url_object: ""`